# How to add where clause in access join query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have query like this.

```
SELECT account.AccountNumber, account.Name, Sum(agro.price*agro.qty) AS Expr1
FROM account,data  INNER JOIN (agro INNER JOIN data ON agro.BillNo = data.BillNo) ON    
account.AccountNumber = data.acno
GROUP BY account.AccountNumber, account.Name;
```

I want to add **where db='true'** this columns is of '**data**' table then how can i do pls help me?

Comment: You should put only the flavour of sql that you are using in the tags for your question. Adding extra tags just adds confusion.

Comment: Thanks @ Filipe Silva

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```sql
SELECT account.AccountNumber, account.NAME, Sum(agro.price * agro.qty) AS Expr1
FROM ((account
INNER JOIN data ON account.AccountNumber = data.acno)
INNER JOIN agro ON agro.BillNo = data.BillNo)
WHERE data.db='true'
GROUP BY account.AccountNumber, account.NAME;
```

You had some confusion in your JOINs, but i think this is what you were aiming for

Comment: Its raised an error "Syntax error (missing operator) in query exp. 'account.AccountNumber = data.acno
INNER JOIN agro ON agro.BillNo = data.BillN'" Please Check..

Comment: Are you sure you copied this exactly like it is? i created a [sample fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d22b5/1) in sql server and it worked right away. I'm not seeing what would need to be changed for access.

Comment: Try the query now with the parenthesis (from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15389708/1385896), it seems that access likes parenthesis around the joins. i did not know this :p). See if it works.