# Joining three worksheets in Report Builder query using ODBC connection to spreadsheet

Tags: sql-server, excel, join, odbc, reportbuilder

This may be a longshot, but I was trying to join three tabs of a spreadsheet in a report builder 3.0 data source. Since I know I can't join two data sets in a table, I'm trying to format the original datasource query. 
It works if I join two tabs; all fields of the two tabs are available. When I add a third, it errors out with

"*ERROR [42000] ... Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression*"

This works:

`SELECT LESigner.Name, AcctSigner.Account
       FROM     [LESigner$] LESigner
     JOIN  [SignersByAccount$] AcctSigner 
     on LESigner.AccountCode = AcctSigner.Account`

This does not

`SELECT LESigner.Name, AcctSigner.Account, LE.ID
       FROM     [LESigner$] LESigner
     JOIN  [SignersByAccount$] AcctSigner 
     on LESigner.AccountCode = AcctSigner.Account
     JOIN  [LegalEntity$] LE 
     on LE.ID = LESigner.ID`

I appreciate any thoughts or advice.

other relevant facts:
Report builder 3.0
Excel 2013

Thanks,
-bc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting parenthesis around JOINs.

Per:  [Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15389553/syntax-error-missing-operator-in-query-expression)

```
SELECT LESigner.Name, AcctSigner.Account, LE.ID
       FROM      ([LESigner$] LESigner
     JOIN  [SignersByAccount$] AcctSigner 
     on LESigner.AccountCode = AcctSigner.Account )
     JOIN  [LegalEntity$] LE 
     on LE.ID = LESigner.ID
```

Comment: Thank you Lewis. I appreciate your answer.